# Loop through all combinations of a multiset elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, multiset

I need to find the best path in a tree, the tree is all possible combinations of elements of a `multiset`.
For example for this `multiset` : A - B - C, the tree would be composed of all the 6 possible combinations :
A - B - C  |
A - C - B  |
B - A - C  |
B - C - A  |
C - A - B  |
C - B - A

[image]

I want to loop trough this tree using the multiset only,

Something like this :

```
// I think this must be initialized, but that is not a problem
Path bestPath;

for (mySet::iterator i(aSet.begin()), e(
                    aSet.end()); i != e; ++i) {  
         Path path = someRecursiveFunction(*i);
         if(criteria(bestPath,path))
              bestPath = path;
         return bestPath;
}
```

and `someRecursiveFunction` must probably be the same, but looping on the rest of the values, I dont want to create a multiset in each node and put the rest on it, since the number of nodes is factorial the size of the multiset,
I can't find a good way to do this ...

Comment: [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: A tree is a graph of a particular form. A graph is defined by two sets - a set of vertices, and a set of edges. You have described one set: "all possible combinations of elements of a `multiset`". Which of the two sets is this one, and how is the other set defined?

Comment: Also, when you say "best path" - a path between what vertex and what other vertex, and "best" by what criteria (given two paths, how do you determine if one is better than the other)?

Comment: I edited the question to show an example of the tree, the tree is composed like this, first the root ( which represent nothing ), then all the elements, et then for each node, we put all the elements but his parents, I hope that this is what an edge mean

Comment: 'path' must be a structure that will allow me to retrieve the path, it contains the best path found from the actual node ( his children ), and the criteria is a function that returns a boolean depending on what I need ( you don't want to know my criteria )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a std::vector as follows
 `std::vector<char> set ={A,B,C}` and call std::next_permutation on top of vector to get all permutations

```
std::next_permutation( std::begin(set), std::end(set));

do {
    //your code for algorithm
    for( auto & x : set)
      std::cout<<x<<" ";
    std::cout<<"\n";
  } while( std::next_permutation( std::begin(set), std::end(set));
```

Comment: Can I use it on a multiset ?

Comment: @Othman: `std::next_permutation` modify the range, so it is not directly useable with `multiset` (that's why you have to copy to `std::vector`).